# Is a stock's trade size history publicly available?

Tags: stocks, historical-data, market-data

For example, if a stock trades 100K shares in a given day then it might have happened in 10 10K-share trades, or 1000 100-share trades, or many other possible combinations.

I would like to know this distribution.  Is this information tracked by any entity, and is it made publicly available?

Comment: This question is not really about product or service recommendation but rather if and where such information can be found.

Answer (score 0):

That is called a '**volume chart**'.

There are many interactive charts available for the purpose.

Here is clear [example](http://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/bharti-airtel-ltd/bhartiartl/532454/).  (just for demonstration but this is for India only)

1) [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=MSFT#%7B%22range%22:%221d%22,%22allowChartStacking%22:true%7D)

2) [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance?q=intel&ei=qQyfVaGHCImIsgHZ7qSABw)

3) And [many more](http://www.bing.com/search?q=best+stock+charts+websites&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=best+stock+charts+websites&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=dfb90a1b25384ca2a4873c1e5521f0b2)

Usually, the stock volume density is presented together (below it) with normal price vs time chart.

**Note:** There is a friendly site about topics like this. [Quant.stackexchange.com](https://quant.stackexchange.com/). Think of checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy the data and process it on your own.

http://www.nyxdata.com/Data-Products/Daily-TAQ

Comment: Thank you for sharing this data source.  I am ideally seeking a solution that already exists vs. having to create one.  If someone can suggest an online solution that will provide the type of information that i am seeking then I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

My Broker and probably many Brokers provide this information in a table format under "Course of Sale". It provides the time, price and volume of each trade on that day.

You could also view this data on a chart in some charting programs. Just set the interval to "Tick by Tick" and look at the volume. "Tick by Tick" will basically place a mark for every trade that is taken and then the volume will tell you the size of that trade.